# Missing file in OpenCV 3.1.0 for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to run this code [Domain Transform Filter](https://github.com/norishigefukushima/domainTransformFilter) on Ubuntu 14.04. This code has been originally written on Windows 7 Visual studio. When I try to run this code on Ubuntu, I get the error

> error: opencv2/core/internal.hpp: No such file or directory

I tried to download this file for Ubuntu but this is specifically related to Windows.

Is there any way to get this file for Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Install an older OpenCV.
The file is for instance contained in `libopencv-core-dev` 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. (So it is not related to Windows.)

If that is not an option, you probably need to correct your existing code for OpenCV 3.

Comment: I did that but now I am getting undefined reference to cvtColor after compliation

Comment: @AshutoshMishra: Hi, There has been a lot of changes made to OpenCv from version 2 to version 3. Thus, you will have to port all the code. Also, the newer version 3 is much better to work with. :)